# JavaScript file is not updated in the prod server but works fine in Dev environments

Tags: javascript

Problem/Issue description:
The JavaScript file is not updated properly in prod server environment, but we deployed the same EAR in dev server where the file is updated and works properly. we also cleared both client & server caches.

Comment: This could be due to a lot of reasons, for example, maybe your production environment uses minified files that are updated with a separate script? Anyway, it's impossible to tell without some clarification.

Comment: This could easily be a permissions issue as well. Have you verified also that there are no errors? Often, in Javascript, when an error is encountered, the script simply halts and stops.

Comment: Since javascript file is not properly updated in deployed folder though the update javascript file found in EAR file, after restarting the server it works fine now.

Comment: try loading the JS file directly in a browser - using a cache breaker and see if the prod server has the updated version. Mostly likely it does and there is some other outness on why an event isn't firing.